# Permission when setup Hadoop Cluster in Pentaho

Tags: hadoop, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I try to setup new hadoop cluster in pentaho 9.3 but i got permission error.
It requires username and password for hdfs but i don't know how to create user and password for hdfs.

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr8OY.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIQms.png)

[I get Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9KAE.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Zxs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop, by default, uses regular OS user accounts. For Linux, you'd use `useradd` command.

Comment: i tried using my user accounts of ubuntu but it still got permission error

Comment: You need to add the users on the Namenode server, then all datanodes, assuming they are different